# upgradable but not upgrading from jammy-updates and jammy-security

Tags: apt, 22.04, gcc

I have upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04, and have two packages in state "upgradable" but not upgrading, which seem to have been kept back:

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  gcc-10-base gcc-10-base:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.

$ apt policy gcc-10-base
gcc-10-base:
  Installed: 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04
  Candidate: 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04
  Version table:
     10.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages
 *** 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     10.3.0-15ubuntu1 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages
```

What would you suggest for cleaning this up?

Comment: `Installed: 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~20.04` vs `Candidate: 10.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04`. Note 20.04 vs 22.04. Suggests a failed release-upgrade.

Comment: The upgrade seems to have finished fine, this may be the only (silent) upgrade problem. How would you suggest proceeding in this case and what should I learn and examine for this?

Comment: If it were I, I'd clone the / partition for backup, then try purging and reinstalling those packages.

Comment: `sudo apt reinstall gcc-10-base=10.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04 gcc-10-base:i386=10.5.0-1ubuntu1~22.04`

Comment: Well I'm trying to also figure out how these two packages relate with one another, whether they are both necessary for a working gcc setup on Ubuntu (22.04). As I understand gcc's latest stable is probably gcc 11, so I assume that these packages are for gcc version 10. figuring out how they relate and whether both of them are necessary for a full gcc is not something I can immediately glean from https://packages.ubuntu.com/, though they do have gcc version 11 for Jammy packaged up  there as far as I can see. I guess i386 is necessary for Intel / not AMD.

Comment: Running through apt reinstall for the two packages gcc-10-base and gcc-10-base:i386 and then an apt upgrade and `apt update` as well, I evidently now got gcc 11 installed, which is fine for me (my own code project still compiles fine after recompiling and running its tests to verify).

Comment: When you run `sudo apt upgrade`, it means you want to have `The following packages have been kept back`. If you don't want that, you need to run `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

Comment: "*I evidently now got gcc 11 installed*" That occurred independently of your `gcc-10-base` packages. It had nothing to do with reinstalling those packages. If you *didn't* have gcc 11 as part of normal 22.04, your system would have been very, very broken. None of the `gcc-10-base` packages included on a stock 20.04 or 22.04 system. A human added them.

Answer (score 0):

First run:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

See if the package is upgraded or not.

If not, use:

```
sudo dpkg -r gcc-10-base:i386
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i386
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

If multiarch is enabled, dpkg may get stuck during release upgrade, and the `gcc-10-base` will be left unconfigured.